# Measures that are invariant under isometries

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, measure-theory, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Quantities like arc-length/area/volume are invariant under isometries (rigid transformations). In Euclidean space we can define these quantities using integration with respect to Lebesgue measure, because the Lebesgue measure is invariant under isometries.

I think the Lebesgue measure is the only such measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with this property -- is this true?

On a more general non-Euclidean space, might there be a measure that's invariant under isometries? And if not, can we still define arclength/area/volume using integrals?

Comment: Do you mean a countably-additive measure? What are you assuming about its sigma-algebra (e.g. are you assuming a Borelean measure?)? When you say $R^n$, do you assume the standard metric? Without clarifying such issues, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: @MoisheKohan honestly, I don't know the answers to these questions. The motivation for my question is to ask about generalizations of this statement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crofton_formula#Statement which uses the "kinematic measure". I'm wondering if this measure is non-unique on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and whether there are analogous ones for noneuclidean spaces.

Comment: My suggestion then is to learn some measure theory first. You are simply not ready to ask a question about it.

Answer (score 1):

There always *exists* a measure which is invariant under isometries*, but you'll need to do a bit more if you want to single out the Lebesgue measure as the "nicest" one. For instance, the zero measure and the counting measure are both invariant under isometries on any space. On spaces with fewer isometries, you will get even more options; many Riemannian manifolds have *no* nontrivial isometries, and so every measure is isometry-invariant.

*On Riemannian manifolds, at least. There there is even a direct generalization of the Lebesgue measure, often called the *Riemann measure*, which is automatically isometry-invariant.

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious to know more about the Riemann measure but am having trouble finding more info. Do you have any references?

Comment: @900edges I don't know of any sources which go into the measure-theoretic detail, but if you're familiar with the [Riemannian volume form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form#Riemannian_volume_form) (or the corresponding density), then you can define the volume of a Borel set pretty straightforwardly, and constructing the measure proceeds exactly as with the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you need some background on integration on manifolds, Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (in particular the section on *densities*) might be a good place to look.